# Two different results produced by Classify

Tags: machine-learning

```
 trainingset = 
ExampleData[{"MachineLearning","Mushroom"},"TrainingData"];
testset = ExampleData[{"MachineLearning","Mushroom"},"TestData"];
Train a classifier on a part of the training set:
SeedRandom[1234];
trainingSample = RandomSample[trainingset, 100];
c=Classify[trainingSample,Method->"GradientBoostedTrees"]
samples = testset[[All, 1]];

probs1=c[samples,"Probabilities"];
probs2=c[#,"Probabilities"]&/@samples;
probs1==probs2
True
```

[image]

If we train the model without setting the Method option, and Mathematica happen choose the GradientBoostTrees Method,
then in prediction process, model gives two different results.

Both two methods to predict are useful.

Is this a bug?
    Following code: Batch Run Until one method is GradientBoostTrees

```
trainingset = ExampleData[{"MachineLearning","Mushroom"},"TrainingData"];
testset = ExampleData[{"MachineLearning","Mushroom"},"TestData"];
samples=testset[[All,1]];
Do[
trainingData=RandomSample[trainingset,100];
c=Classify[trainingData];
Print@trainingData[[1]];
method=c[[1]]["Model","Method"];
probs1=c[samples,"Probabilities"];
probs2=c[#,"Probabilities"]&/@samples;
check=probs1[[All,1]]-probs2[[All,1]]//Chop[#,10^-5]&//Union;
Print[method,"=",check],{i,10}]
```

[image: problem]

---

The problem seems it was caused by some Processor and FeatureExtractor
In some times, the result is extremely different, which means the model is useless.

If we remove Missing data and Boolean Data in dataset, the problem is still there.

```
trainingset = ExampleData[{"MachineLearning","Mushroom"},"TrainingData"];
testset = ExampleData[{"MachineLearning","Mushroom"},"TestData"];
samples=testset[[All,1]];
rules={Missing[]->"Missing"};
dataTrain=trainingset/.rules;
Do[
trainingData=RandomSample[dataTrain,100];
c=Classify[trainingData,Method->"GradientBoostedTrees",FeatureExtractor->"DimensionReducedVector"];
Print@trainingData[[1]];
method=c[[1]]["Model","Method"];
processor=c[[1]]["Model","Processor"];
Print[processor];
If[method!="GradientBoostedTrees",Continue,
probs1=c[samples/.rules,"Probabilities"];
probs2=c[#,"Probabilities"]&/@samples;
check=probs1[[All,1]]-probs2[[All,1]]//Chop[#,10^-5]&//Union;
Print[method,"=",check]],{i,10}]
```

[image]

**The following result is funny**
The same sample in a batch will get two different results in predict.

My test notebook is [here](https://github.com/HyperGroups/MathematicaMachineLearning/blob/master/Bugs/Bug%40BatchPredict%40GBDTMethod.nb).

[image]

Comment: Please provide a reproducible code with a fixed random seed for the sample.

Comment: @swish Updated,

Comment: Can confirm some funky behavior in tree related Classify methods, probabilities may differ drastically whether one predicts samples in bulk or not.

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer, but a more concrete example of when its happening

```
trainingset = 
  ExampleData[{"MachineLearning", "Mushroom"}, "TrainingData"];
testset = ExampleData[{"MachineLearning", "Mushroom"}, "TestData"];
samples = testset[[All, 1]];
BlockRandom[
 trainingData = RandomSample[trainingset, 1000];
 c = Classify[trainingData, Method -> "DecisionTree"],
 RandomSeeding -> 1
 ]
c[samples[[79]], "Probabilities"]
c[samples[[{1, 2, 79}]], "Probabilities"][[-1]]
```

At first run the last two probabilities are the same, but rut this code again, and it yields a complete opposite predictions!

Comment: Your example is designated the Tree method in Classify, that's a great found.

Comment: I found the problem is probably caused by preprocessing of Classify. If we encode the features manually, we can partly solve the problem.